# android - how to change the fb logo size on facebook login button

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

so I have an Android application and I want to do a Facebook login. For that purpose I implemented the Facebook Login button in my layout. It's the following code now:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />
```

The problem is, that the Facebook logo is too small:

fb logo too small

[image: fb logo too small]

Is there a way to make it bigger?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Create custom Button .

Comment: Make width and height to `match_parent` or customize your own button.

Answer (score 0):

give your width and height on dp value

> ```
> android:layout_width="600dp"
> android:layout_height="wrap_content"
> ```

or you have to create more large size image 
Note: i believe that you have already added all the screen sizes of drawables

cheerz

Comment: "Note: i believe that you have already added all the screen sizes of drawables", what do you mean by that? I just tried to give the com_facebook_button_icon_blue.png more pixel (from 42x42 to 70x70) and add it to drawables, but the changes don't adapt....the button image is saves under: app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4 but it doesn't help if I change here the size...

Comment: please follow this guidelines https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: doesn't help me here: " Note: i believe that you have already added all the screen sizes of drawables" I guess this is done automatically? Otherwise it wouldn't have shown up at all...Did you mean just to check if those drawables are there or to resize them?

Comment: no u have to create or resize images according to the given document, for all the sizes manually(or by using any software) and import it to project drawable folders. that i given android guildlines provide sufficient details regarding the uis creation.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom Facebook button and change visibility on the native Facebook button:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/facebookView"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_frame"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Sign_in_facebook_button"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Add a listener to your fake button and simulate click:

```
facebookView.setOnClickListener(this);
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.facebookView){
       facebookButton.performClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer! stil don't get the whole idea: what is "btn_frame"? Do I need to design my own button image?

Comment: basically I create my own "button" which sets the background to  "btn_frame" which basically is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLHHm.png (but I need to modify the facebook logo size by myself in that new btn_frame image?)

Comment: how aobut if I just add this line: android:background="@drawable/btn_frame" to my code snippet above? With the new designed button?

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable with name com_facebook_button_icon.xml add anything inside it FB login button will override as it uses as drawableleft.

LoginButton:

```
   this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                AppCompatResources.getDrawable(
                        getContext(), com.facebook.common.R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon),
                null,
                null,
                null);
```